# Using a string variable for a database query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a string and use this in my database query. This code doesn't work:

```
<% $cat_str = "'cat_id= ? OR cat_id=? OR cat_id=? ', '14', '15', '25'" %>   
<% @afilliate = Afilliates.find(Categories.where($cat_str).order('created_at DESC').last.af_id %>
```

However, this code works:

```
 <% @afilliate = Afilliates.find(Categories.where('cat_id= ? OR cat_id=? OR cat_id=? ', '14', '15', '25').order('created_at DESC').last.af_id )%>
```

The strange thing about this is that I print the generated string in the first code block and it prints exactly the string that I use in the second query, which works. Any ideas? THanks.

Comment: Why are you putting a call to your model inline in your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example you have two strings

```
'cat_id= ? OR cat_id=? OR cat_id=? '
```

and

```
'14', '15', '25'
```

In your first example you only have a single string, which `where` doesn't understand.

It would be better to run `Category.where(cat_id: [14, 15, 25])` if there is a way to make your code do that, i.e. `cat_ids = [14, 15, 25)` then `Category.where(cat_id: cat_ids)`.

As a side note, putting `$` in front of a ruby variable name has a special meaning (it is a global variable), which I don't imagine is intended in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The previous comment helped me a lot and I really thank the guy who saved my day :-)

What actually works is this:

```
 <% $cat_str = "14, 15, 25" %>
<% @afilliate = Afilliates.find(Categories.where(cat_id: [$cat_str]).order('created_at ASC').offset(2).last.af_id ) %>
```